# Remote file transfer (rsync, scp, sftp) times out

Tags: rsync, scp, file-transfer

I am running into a problem where my connection times out when I try to transfer a file remotely from a MAC OS (11.2.3) to Ubuntu 18.04.05. I am able to connect and have write access to files via `ssh`. Here are examples using three different methods of file transferring, all seeming to give a similar error, which makes me think it has something to do with my local configuration or a firewall, but am at a loss on how to troubleshoot this.

Note that I've replaced my username and IP with fake fillers, but I'm using the real names when running the script.

**ssh**

This works fine, but putting here just in case it is helpful.

```
ssh -p 9922 [remote-user]@[remote-IP]
```

**scp**

Running the following code:

```
scp -vvvP 9922 /Users/[local-user]/Desktop/moving-files-ssh.txt [remote-user]@[remote-IP]:~/
```

Results in the connection timing out, not requesting a password or anything:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host [remote-IP], user [remote-user], command scp -v -t ~/
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname [remote-IP] is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to [remote-IP] [[remote-IP]] port 9922.
debug1: connect to address [remote-IP] port 9922: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host [remote-IP] port 9922: Operation timed out
lost connection
```

I have also tried this the other way, logging into the remote machine and attempting to transfer files back to my local machine via scp, and ran into the same issue.

**sftp**

I am unable to establish the sftp connection:

```
sftp -oPort=9922 [remote-user]@[remote-IP]
```

The cursor seems to hang for several minutes and then prints out:

```
ssh: connect to host [remote-IP] port 9922: Operation timed out
```

**rsync**

Similar problem as to scp:

```
rsync -ahvz -e 'ssh -p9922' /Users/[local-user]/Desktop/moving-files-ssh.txt [remote-user]@[remote-IP]:/
```

Results in:

```
ssh: connect to host [remote-IP] port 9922: Operation timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

This also sometimes results in error code 12.

**ssh config**

Here is what is in my ssh configurations:

```
# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
```

Output from running `ssh -vvv`

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname XXX.XX.XXX.XX is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to XXX.XX.XXX.XX [XXX.XX.XXX.XX] port 9922.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to XXX.XX.XXX.XX:9922 as 'username'
debug3: put_host_port: [XXX.XX.XXX.XX]:9922
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [XXX.XX.XXX.XX]:9922
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: put_host_port: [XXX.XX.XXX.XX]:9922
debug3: put_host_port: [XXX.XX.XXX.XX]:9922
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [XXX.XX.XXX.XX]:9922
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [XXX.XX.XXX.XX]:9922
debug1: Host '[XXX.XX.XXX.XX]:9922' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
```

Comment: Try using `ssh -vvv`. It'll give you an obscene amount of chatter but it should at least tell you *why* its connection keeps closing.

Comment: Do you have lower than 1500 MTU in the path (along an ICMP firewall issue)?, for example caused by a tunnel? You could check this on MacOS with something similar to `ping -D -s 1472 ubuntu-ip` and on Ubuntu something similar to `ping -M do -s 1472 macos-ip`. If they fail try a lower size value (eg: 1300). If this then succeeds that would be it (and you should update the question with the results). If not, that was just a failed random attempt at guessing what is wrong. (nb: for IPv6, the initial size should be 1452 instead)

Comment: Thanks @Shadur. I tried what you suggested (scp -vvv) and received the same amount of detail as above when I had used `scp -vvvP`. The `ssh` is working fine, should I still look at the verbose version of that?

Comment: @A.B I tried your suggestion for a range of 100 to 1472 and received the same each time: `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0`, so it doesn't seem to be that issue. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: If this never worked, the test failed to discover if there is or there isn't the issue. It's useful only when it works for some cases and not for others. Anyway I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Got it. Yeah everything was working fine last week and I was able to transfer files so I am not sure what happened

Comment: Connection timed out suggests that whatever's on port 9922 at the receiving end isn't listening.  Can you run that remote SSH server in debug mode, crank up its logging to VERBOSE in the setting?

Comment: I've updated the question with the `ssh -vvv` output, but it seems that the port is working okay in that instance at least